# Is it possible to move glutInit to my init function?

Tags: c, opengl, glut

I use such main function for my c program using glut ( it works) :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  char filename[MAXLINE];

  /* Read in the file (allocates space for Picture) */
  if (argc < 2) 
    {
    printf ("Enter the name of a PPM or PGM file: ");
    scanf("%s", filename);
    readPPM ((char *)filename, &Picture);
    }
    else { readPPM (argv[1], &Picture); }

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    MyInit();
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(PassiveMouseMotion); // mouse move with no key pressed 
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Key);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Is it possible and good idea to move some code to myInit function and use :

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{

    MyInit(@argc, argv);
    glutPassiveMotionFunc(PassiveMouseMotion); // mouse move with no key pressed 
    glutReshapeFunc(Reshape);
    glutDisplayFunc(Draw);
    glutKeyboardFunc(Key);

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

( above code does not work , it is a proposition)

??

Comment: the answers to this question will be subjective.  You do however need to call `glutInit` _before_ any other command line argument processing, and then perform your own processing on whatever arguments are left unconsumed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Possible? Yes. Good idea? Don't know. It might be nice to have all init-related code in one place I guess.

If `MyInit` is declared as

```
void MyInit(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    // other init code etc... 
}
```

You should be able to call it from `main`using:

```
MyInit(argc, argv);
```

I doubt that `glutInit` cares from which function it's called, as long as it's called in a proper way, and before you do any GL stuff.

Comment: Thx. It works fine. Why Glut do not use it as other  functions like : glutInit(MyInit) ?

Comment: @Adam I honestly have no idea why the developers choose this implementation instead of using a callback. My guess is for portability or ease of use, but that's pure speculation.

Comment: GLUT dates back to the mid 1990s when the most common OpenGL system was an SGI workstation and it was normal to run programs by typing commands instead of clicking icons. glutInit was very nearly the first thing your GL program did, and the command line arguments could specify (on SGI and other Unix) things like displaying on a remote computer instead of the one in front of you.